# Mailgun HTTP POST to with Rails 3 - (undefined method `rewind' for #<String:0xb701ace0>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Does anyone have any theories about this?

I have a feeling this is a Rails 3.x bug.

I'm using a service called mailgun that routes incoming e-mails to url's for further processing. Rails 3 chokes on these requests. Rails 2 does not.

I'm at a loss. I'm not sure exactly where the issue is.

```
Started POST "/posts/upload" for 174.37.214.195 at Fri Mar 11 20:22:41 -0500 2011
  SQL (0.1ms)  SET search_path TO public
  SQL (0.2ms)  SHOW client_min_messages
  SQL (0.1ms)  SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'
  SQL (0.1ms)  SET standard_conforming_strings = on
  SQL (0.1ms)  SET client_min_messages TO 'notice'
  SQL (0.4ms)  SET time zone 'UTC'
  SQL (0.1ms)  SHOW TIME ZONE

NoMethodError (undefined method `rewind' for #<String:0xb6d1c624>):


Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)
Error during failsafe response: ActionView::Template::Error
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:10:in `parameters'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb:3:in `__usr_lib_ruby_gems_____gems_actionpack_______lib_action_dispatch_middleware_templates_rescues_diagnostics_erb___359554262__609638518_0'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `send'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `render'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:59:in `_render_template'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in `_render_template'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render_without_haml'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-3.0.25/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:13:in `render'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:88:in `rescue_action_locally'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:68:in `render_exception'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:213:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:30
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6


Started POST "/posts" for 174.37.214.196 at Fri Mar 11 20:24:24 -0500 2011

NoMethodError (undefined method `rewind' for #<String:0xb701ace0>):


Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (1.1ms)
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yup, it was a debatable bug in Rack. It was resolved with a mixin and future versions of Rails will include a version of Rack without the issue.

Comment: Can you point a link to a gist with the mixin you are using? I'm running into the same problem...

Comment: Just confirmed that Rails 3.1.0.rc1 (Rack version 1.3) fixes the problem.

Comment: So for those of us that can't or won't upgrade to 3.1 can you tell us which mixing you used to resolve the problem?

Answer (score -3):

Two ideas: either your routing is configured differently, or there's "forgery protection" going on. Not exactly a rails expert here... :)